# How to decode a cookie from the header of a websocket connection handshake? (Ruby)

Tags: ruby, cookies, rack, eventmachine

I am running a `Sinatra` app within an `EventMachine.run` loop and in my `ws.onopen` method I wish to check the `handshake` header's cookie to ensure that the incoming request is coming from a registered user of my webapp.

My `Sinatra` app includes the following:

```
use Rack::Session::Cookie,  :key => COOKIE_KEY,
                            :path => '/',
                            :expire_after => 2592000, #30 days
                            :secret => COOKIE_SECRET
```

and my `ws.onopen` method looks like this (trimmed)

```
ws.onopen { |handshake|
  cookie, bakesale = handshake.headers['Cookie'].split('=')
  rack_cookie = Rack::Session::Cookie.new(MyApp, {
    :key => COOKIE_KEY,
    :path => '/',
    :expire_after => 2592000, #30 days
    :secret => COOKIE_SECRET
  })
  decoded = rack_cookie.coder.decode(bakesale)
  puts "decoded: #{decoded}"

}
```

The value of `cookie` matches my `COOKIE_KEY` just fine, however the value of `decoded` is `nil`

How should I decode the incoming cookie data?

-- some time later --

I've changed the above slightly to

```
ws.onopen { |handshake|
  cookie, bakesale = handshake.headers['Cookie'].split('=')
  rack_cookie = Rack::Session::Cookie.new(MyApp, {
    :key => COOKIE_KEY,
    :path => '/',
    :expire_after => 2592000, #30 days
    :secret => COOKIE_SECRET,
    :coder => Rack::Session::Cookie::Base64.new
  })

  puts rack_cookie.coder.decode(bakesale)

}
```

and that outputs

`?q?[?????ov??????to?Z???294cb6e2b95e9?##v3???#c&F3#SC?CSC#CSs?c3sSCCs?cCm;FI"__FLASH__;F{I"   user;FU:Moped::BSO?㣤?&?V7D?B!`

which looks like it needs marshalling.

However `Marshal.load (rack_cookie.coder.decode(bakesale))` throws an exception, saying `dump format error for symbol(0x10)`

-- and even more time later --

I also tried `rack_cookie.coder.decode(bakesale.split('--').first)`

which resulted in

`??H?d????=?d:ETI"E7ce599b294cb6e2b95e9?##v3???#c&F3#SC?CSC#CSs?c3sSCCs?cCm;FI"__FLASH__;F{I" user;FU:Moped::BSO?㣤?&?V7D?B!`

So as you can see, there is a minor difference, but either way I need to somehow turn that into a valid hash.

Marshal.load(rack_cookie.coder.decode(bakesale.split('--').first)) still results in `dump format error for symbol(0x10)` either way.

So I feel I'm closer, but no cigar as yet.

Comment: I have put the whole example framework up in a gist to help clarify this issue.  https://gist.github.com/davesag/5506864

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is to use `Rack::Utils.unencode`.

I now have this working

`Marshal.load(rack_cookie.coder.decode(Rack::Utils.unescape(bakesale.split('--').first)))` decodes perfectly to the hash I need, allowing me to extract the user ID. W00t!

Many thanks to User **spastorino** over at https://github.com/rack/rack/issues/551 for pointing me in the right direction.